# How to create RSA SHA 256 SignatureEncryption and SymmetricKeyEncryption with ASP.NET VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, symmetric-key, rsa-sha256

I have to do Payment Integration with bank where my account will be debited and vendor's account will be credited. for that Bank need **RequestsignatureEncryptedValue** and **SymmetricKeyEncryptedValue**

1. RSA SHA 256 -> payload -> Clients private key  -> signed payload (signature)
2. Generate random alphanumeric 32 bytes string (Symmetric Key) | Example: vtxvqwvxuyvqwxbwbxibchbwcibwcwbi
3. (IV+Signature) <--> (Symmetric Key without base 64) -- Encryption (AES/CBC/PKCS7)Algorithm byte[] <--> base64encoding ==> **RequestsignatureEncryptedValue**
4. (Symmetric Key without base 64) <--> (api-uat.xyzbank.com) xyzbank publickey -- Encryption (RSA/ECB/PKCS1)Algo <--> base64encoding ==> **SymmetricKeyEncryptedValue**

How can I do this with asp vb.net? I am new to bank integration. I have all the SSL details.

Comment: Your payment integrator should offer some examples in their documentation. Who are they? Have you tried anything?